# Folland's Riesz representation theorem for $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

[image: Proof of Folland]

I am reading the Folland's theorem 6.15. I have a hard time understanding the last part, where we assume $\mu$ is arbitrary. My questions are:

(1) How do we know $g_F=g_E$ a.e. on $E$? Could someone give me some more details please?

(2) How do we get $\int|g_F|^q+\int|g_{A-F}|^q=\int|g_A|^q$?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $ E \subset X$, Folland identifies a function $f \in L^p(E)$ with its extension to $X$ that vanishes identically outside $E$.

For your first query: $g_F 1_E$ satisfies the defining property of $g_E$
(namely $\phi(f)=\int_E f g_F 1_E$ holds for all $f \in L^p(E)$.)
Thus uniqueness of $g_E$ implies that $g_F 1_E=g_E$.

For your second query: Note that $h=|g_A|^{q-1} \cdot{\rm sgn}(g)$ is in $L^p$ because $p(q-1)=q$. Write $B=A \setminus F$. Now
$$\int_F h 1_F g_F+ \int_B h 1_B g_B=\phi(h1_F)+\phi(h1_B)=\phi(h)=\int_A hg_A$$
gives the identity you want.